# Composer Authentication with DataPower as OAuth Provider

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, ibm-datapower, hyperledger-composer

I have been reviewing this Hyperledger Composer tutorial https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/integrating/enabling-rest-authentication.html. Is it possible to use the IBM DataPower Gateway as the OAuth provider?

Answer (score 0):

it should be possible to use IBM DataPower Gateway as the OAuth Provider